# Outlook 2010 Add-In: How to customize "From/To/CC/Subject" pane?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm currently working on an Outlook 2010 Add-In with C#. Is there any way to customize the "From/To/CC/Subject" pane in Outlook 2010?

Specifically, I hope to implement the following functionality:

1. Add a new field below the subject of an email
2. Add two icons on the right of that area

I need to do that both for email previews and when reading an email in a new window. See this [ImageShack](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/9274/exampleqq.png) pic as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize this part of the Outlook user interface - as of my researches I've done for a client who just requested that. Here's my link list (with negative results):

[How to customize Email Send button in Outlook?](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=8687&MID=44275#message44275)

[Add controls to existing ribbon group in Office (VSTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861630/add-controls-to-existing-ribbon-group-in-office-vsto)

[Modifying Built-in Ribbon Controls](http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-studio-tools-for-office/modifying-builtin-ribbon-controls--newbie-question-43061.shtml)

[Add a control / button inside the group - Ribbon Bar](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31603096/add-a-control--button-inside-the-group--ribbon-bar.aspx)

[Outlook addin to add a custom "Send" button next to existing Send button in mail compose window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/outlookdev/thread/cae30fd6-c9c9-4975-ba18-2f52aa1aa477)

[how to place a button next to the send mail (system button)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/outlookdev/thread/4e52df9e-643a-468a-8a19-c33ecdf93eb6)

[Can I add a custom “Send” button to Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997326/can-i-add-a-custom-send-button-to-outlook)