# Adding button to outlook menu

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook-addin that needs to have a custom way of sending emails. Is it possible to add a custom send button to the new message dialog in Outlook? [image: New Message Form]

Comment: You cannot customize this part. Please see [my link list in this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052233/outlook-2010-add-in-how-to-customize-from-to-cc-subject-pane/7054714#7054714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the "area" where the "Send" button is located is not customizable.

One work-around would be to add a "panel" below the marked section, and have a button there... or, you could create a custom type of items altogether.